# Translating a large file with small API rate limits on Google Speech API

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client, google-speech-api

I have an audio file that is 24 hours and 100MB that I want to transcribe/translate using nodejs and the Google Speech API. The Google Speech API will not support processing more than 1 min of audio nor 10MB of data at a time.

How can I get this much data transcribed please?

My repo :

https://github.com/nguyentienviet123456/api-google-speechtotext-nodejs

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and update your question according:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your post so that it might be a bit clearer what you were intending to do. I clarified the title and re-wrote the text with clearer English. I hope I got your question correct! If not, please revert it back and someone else will try.

Try putting your problem right up front: How did you get where you are? What are you trying to do? What have you already tried?

Best of luck!

Comment: I would add that I don't know if stack overflow supports what you are trying to accomplish, so you may not get good answers here. If you are trying to get paid services for free, then this is the wrong place to ask about that. Thank you for visiting and I hope you enjoy the community!